# Sorting Bar chart in C3js

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js, c3.js

I was looking forward to sort the bars on simple bar-chart, if it is possible something like below i mentioned.

```
var chart = c3.generate({ data: { columns: [['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],], type: 'bar', order: 'desc' }, })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://c3js.org/reference.html#data-order) the `data.order` property is restricted to pie or donut charts. You have to sort the data before creating the chart to get ordered bars.

```
var data1 = [130, 100, 140, 200, 150, 50].sort(function(a,b) { return a-b; })
var chart = c3.generate({
  data: {
    columns: [
        ["data1"].concat(data1)  // old-school
//      ["data1", ...data1]      // ES6 flavor

    ]
  }
})
```

Comment: You are right, they dont have any option for sorting, http://c3js.org/reference.html#data-xSort. I could not understand the reason behind to restrict the sort option only pie or donut chart.So i have to sort the data before passing to create chart.